# how Can I send text box value using a html.actionlink

Tags: html.actionlink

[image]

How to put textbox value to html.actionlink as parameters to a controller can?

Comment: my controller looks like thispublic ActionResult Confirm(ordering ordering, int id,string number_order)
        {   
            ordering order = db.orderings.Find(id);
            int number = unchecked((int)order.Number_of_Items);
            int numberoforders=int.Parse(number_order);
            number = number - numberoforders;
            order.Number_of_Items = number;
            db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }